# Парсинг тэга img BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть такой html код https://pastebin.com/wvuRtqzi

Хочу из тэга img вытащить первый small, но мои попытки терпят неудачи

Для начала я попробовал получить сам тэг img. У меня это получилос

```
find("img")
```

Потом начал в тэге img искать small

```
find("img").find("small")
```

Но тут начали выскакивать ошибки на подобии этой (ошибки потому что я пробовал другие методы типа ['small'] или обрезку [:1]

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<small>` находится у вас внутри content атрибута в `<img>` элементе в отдельном HTML документе:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML)
img = soup.find('img', content=True)
assert img is not None
content_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(img['content'])

print(content_soup.small.get_text())
```

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых, внутри тега img других тегов быть не может. Во-вторых, чтобы не было ошибок, надо почитать документацию и понять, что же возвращает метод find. В-третьих, по моему личному мнению, BeautifulSoup - пустая трата времени, так как порой генерит такой код, который потом само распарсить не может.

Comment: на счет того что в теге img других быть не может говорили мне все. Но на сайте (не моем) именно так и сделано и мне нужно как то его распарсить

Comment: @user210886 а в каком диве находится тег?